# MS Access enter parameter value for report

Tags: ms-access-2007

I have a report/letter with a query as its record source.

Some of the paragraphs I would like the user to be able to amend instead of asking each time it needs a change.

I set up a local table called LetterWording; this has one record with four short text fields which contain the wording for the paragraphs which need amending.

In the letter I added textboxes for these paragraphs with the control source pointing at the relevant field (e.g. =[LetterWording]![1stInterviewParagraph1]).

However, when I open up the letter in report view I get the Enter Parameter Value popup asking for LetterWording.

If I click OK without entering anything (I don't know what it wants anyway) the letter opens and those four paragraphs say #Error.

Can anybody please advise what I'm doing wrong here?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Just me being silly. As I can't/don't want to add to the original record source query I should add these paragraphs as sub-reports.